# How to reuse a XAML component and it's ".cs" code without coping it?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, .net-core

What is (the best / one) way to reuse a custom XAML component? Let's say, a component that was derived from System.Windows.Controls.Page. How to link it to any solution, with no namespace and/or reference errors and without copying?

I've already seen the ResourceDictionary property but it doesn't look like it's actually somewhat similar to component's direct linking. Tell me If I'm wrong here.

I need to use syntax as follows in any current project's .xaml file:

```
<ExternalCustomControl 
Source = "../CustomControl.xaml" 
Implementation="../CustomControl.cs">
</ExternalCustomControl>
```

Comment: [Pack URIs in Windows Presentation Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/aa970069(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: [Merged resource dictionaries (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-merged-dictionaries?view=netdesktop-5.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, does the merged resource dictionaries only allow to define a "property group" of a xaml element? Like <Element PropertyName ="{StaticResource ResourceName}">. Because I haven't found an example of an absolutely external element that can be imported into the xaml Control from different project / namespace, something like : <ExternalElement Source = ".../element.xaml">